# Swift Combine - Create publisher for CoreLocation

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, core-location, combine, publisher

I have only started learning combine, so it's still a little fuzzy to me. I would like to create a custom `Publisher`, that would use `CLLocationManager` to expose current user location. I would like it to work in such a way, that `locationManager` only starts updating location when there are some subscribers connected. And after all subscribers were removed, canceled, etc, then it should stop updating location. Is this possible to do? How can I create such a `publisher`? Also is this the right approach, or is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Have a peek here: https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/

Comment: Thank you, I have seen this, but this behaves a little differently than I would like it to. You need to explicitly tell it to start notification updates, where I would like it to automatically start/stop updating location, depending on if there are some subscribers connected to the publisher.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/broadwaylamb/OpenCombine, from there you should be able to implement your own PassthroughSubject by expanding existing PassthroughSubject to say PassthroughLocationSubject that holds a reference to location manager. Then when you add first subscription you start location manager, and when you remove last subscriber you stop location manager, and on each location update/failure you send the value through send() method.  Hope that helps

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe because PassthroughSubject is a class it can't be used with @State like Timer.publish can which is a struct.

Answer (score 8):

The basics of what you want are pretty straightforward. There's an example from [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine) that wraps CoreLocation with a object that acts as a proxy, returning a publisher of [`CLHeading`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clheading) updates.

CoreLocation itself doesn't automatically start or stop that sort of thing, and in the proxy object I copied that pattern to allow you to manually start and stop the updating process.

The core of the code is in https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/blob/master/UIKit-Combine/LocationHeadingProxy.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreLocation

final class LocationHeadingProxy: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let mgr: CLLocationManager
    private let headingPublisher: PassthroughSubject<CLHeading, Error>
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<CLHeading, Error>

    override init() {
        mgr = CLLocationManager()
        headingPublisher = PassthroughSubject<CLHeading, Error>()
        publisher = headingPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()

        super.init()
        mgr.delegate = self
    }

    func enable() {
        mgr.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func disable() {
        mgr.stopUpdatingHeading()
    }
    // MARK - delegate methods
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        headingPublisher.send(newHeading)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        headingPublisher.send(completion: Subscribers.Completion.failure(error))
    }
}
```

This doesn't quite do everything you asked, in that it doesn't automatically start updates upon subscription, but I suspect you could expand this to enable that capability.

So far I haven't delved into making my own publishers by implementing all the methods required by the protocol, so I don't have detail extending to that mechanism. Combine itself has the concept of [ConnectablePublisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/connectablepublisher) for when you want explicit control over the updates, although most of the publishers and operators trigger on either creation of the publisher or subscription.

In general, *IF* you should do so is better answered by your use case. In some instances, you're creating the pipelines and subscribing before you're updating views - if that's the case, then holding off on asking for the background updates would save you some processing power and energy consumption.

In the UIKit examples that use this CoreLocation publisher, I also have the mechanisms in place to verify permissions have been requested to allow for Location updates, embedded within an example view controller: https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes/blob/master/UIKit-Combine/HeadingViewController.swift

Comment: If you are targeting the UI with the heading you would be better off formatting your string in the delegate method in this object and setting it on a published property. That way the formatting is only done when the heading changes and not on every UI update, e.g. if this was an ObservableObject for SwiftUI.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to Combine but here is [my attempt](https://gist.github.com/malhal/22f534d47d620216c25d812af9bcc227) I just created today so it is a work in progress and may not have been done correctly. The idea is to use `CLLocationManager` how it was designed, i.e. multiple instances where needed.

```
// Requirements: a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription entry in Info.plist and call requestWhenInUseAuthorization
  
import Foundation
import Combine
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationManager {
    public static func publishLocation() -> LocationPublisher{
        return .init()
    }

    public struct LocationPublisher: Publisher {
        public typealias Output = CLLocation
        public typealias Failure = Never

        public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
            let subscription = LocationSubscription(subscriber: subscriber)
            subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
        }
        
        final class LocationSubscription<S: Subscriber> : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, Subscription where S.Input == Output, S.Failure == Failure{
            var subscriber: S
            var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            
            init(subscriber: S) {
                self.subscriber = subscriber
                super.init()
                locationManager.delegate = self
            }

            func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
            
            func cancel() {
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }
            
            func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
                for location in locations {
                    _ = subscriber.receive(location)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tester**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class Locator : ObservableObject {
    @Published var location = CLLocation()
    var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    init() {
        
    }
    
    func start(){
        cancellable = CLLocationManager.publishLocation()
            .assign(to: \.location, on: self)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var locator = Locator()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Location \(locator.location)")
        }
        .onAppear(){
            locator.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Next I plan to add `publishAuthorization` and have a pipeline. I'd also like to supply a configuration param to the init, so that if there are multiple subscribers they can have a location manager configured in the same way, e.g. `distanceFilter`.